# Why can't the rebels kill Vader like the clone troopers killed the Jedi in Order 66?

Tags: star-wars

We all know the scene in ROTS where the Jedi are getting purged in the Temple and the clones surround them as seen here:

[image: Pic]
My question is why the rebels couldn't do the same thing with Vader. Is he exceptionally good with the light saber or are the rebels just not on an equal scale to the clone troopers?

Comment: We're lead to assume that Vader is just a bad *ss that he would use his precognition to avoid ever getting in that situation.  The Jedis were being blocked by Palpatine.

Comment: When in Star Wars did the rebels get an opportunity to ambush Vader and overwhelm him with their greater numbers?

Comment: @Valorum - SPOILER ALERT: End of Rogue One.

Comment: @Valorum Smaller SPOILER ALERT: every time he isn't in a TIE fighter. Seriously, the people playing him in Battlefront are essentially performing the role faithfully - guy just walks into danger.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida - At the end of Rogue One it's a very cramped and claustrophobic fight within a small corridor. I hardly see that there's scope to suround him

Comment: @Valorum You don't need to surround him so much as shoot so much that he can't block it all. Just ask [Jedi Master](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Coleman_Trebor) [Sooki-Ess De'th](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=thp-jvY6OFM).

Comment: @Terriblefan - I blame Windu for that one. Who the hell decided that a fish-faced guy with no lightsaber skills  (and who's obviously from a water planet) should try to apprehend Dooku.

Comment: @Valorum [*Vader Down*](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars%3A_Vader_Down)?

Comment: @JasonBaker - A prime example of why you don't bring grenades when fighting a Sith/Magneto http://pm1.narvii.com/5976/786298f29370bc2f7f35e045d4e52791082f91af_hq.jpg

Comment: I'd say two reasons: the dark side is far stronger than the light, and the most rebels have never seen a Jedi (or at least not encountered one for 17 years).  They simply don't know how to fight him, and have no time to come up with tactics.

Comment: ...because that's not exactly how you kill a jedi/sith/guy-with-a-stick/force user. [Do you wanna know how to kill a force user?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UPeI4mX8Nus)

Comment: Because the concept of 'Order 66' is nonsensical rubbish that was thought up much later than the (original) Star Wars movies were made.

Comment: @MilesRout Because, judging by the original movies, it should be *much easier* to kill Jedi?

Answer (score 83):

1. Tactics (Element of surprise).

   Jedi had no idea they were going to be attacked. When they did know (Yoda), they were successful.
2. Tactics (Vader is rarely in bad tactical situation)

   As commenters noted, Vader is almost never seen in canon in a dire tactical situation like the video in OP's question. He doesn't get surrounded. The only major fight we see (Rogue One), he faces people in narrow corridors, where the numerical superiority is significantly diminished.

   Whether that's due to luck, or deliberate avoidance of bad tactical position due to Force precognition, isn't known.
3. The Force access.

   All throughout prequel timeline it's stressed that Sidious diminished Jedi's ability to sense the Force.

   Vader doesn't suffer from that handicap.
4. Vader is Anakin Skywalker++.

   One of the strongest Force Users ever even back as a Jedi, with Midichlo&^n count dialed up to 11. The Chosen One. Then, trained by the best defensive swordsman in the Order (Obi-Wan, according to Novelization). Then, trained on top of that as a Sith by Sidious, who bested even Yoda in combat.
5. The Dark Side is stronger. He has access to skills Jedi did not.

   Remember, even as a Jedi, he bested - in direct combat - Darth Tyrannus, once he opened himself up to the Dark Side (novelization to ROTS covers that in detail). Dooku happened to be one of the best fighters in the order even before becoming a Sith, and who bested Obi-Wan in combat, easily, twice.
6. Compassion.

   Jedi Generals were likely hesitant to kill clone troopers they were fighting side by side in. Vader has no special affinity for the Rebels.
7. Yes, Rebels are inferior.

   Some Rebels are amazing fighters, but most are not. Clones were all cloned from Jango Fett and trained to an amazing extent. And Rebels have virtually no armor, as opposed to clones.

   I don't think that would have mattered to Vader either way, to be honest (witness Yoda and Obi-Wan surviving O66 attacks), but it may be a minor factor as well.

Comment: Additionally, Vader has an "OH S*%^!" factor that goes to 11. Most of the Jedi Masters could do what he does, but only he does so in a way that makes most of the rebels run away screaming -- instead of turning around and shooting at him until he dies.

Comment: One point though in the comics (canon) there is seemingly a scene where vader IS surrounded by rebels.....armed with blasters and even anti tank weapons...........and HE tells them to lie down their weapons or die.....and they do the later

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - Canon, the novelization is not.

Comment: @Adamant - actually, it is 100% canon under Disney, with exception of specific facts contradicted by the film. Blame \@Richard

Comment: @DVK-in-exile - I read the tweets and so forth myself, and the implication seems to me to be that it is only canon when it *accords* with the film.

Comment: @DVK- in-exile - https://mobile.twitter.com/pablohidalgo/status/712038897065304067, https://twitter.com/delreystarwars/status/461579307341840384. "Maybe it happened, maybe it didn't."

Comment: @Thomas: Yes.  He was a badass, and had a reputation.  Sure, there was a *chance* for the Rebels to take him down, but they were also in a bad tactical situation - close-quarters is no place to use anti-material weaponry, when you surround a target your backstop (if you miss) is your buddies, and Vader had enough of a rep that even if they were ***sure*** they could take him down, the knew they'd take hideous losses.  He bluffed(ish) and it worked.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I also read that the clone troopers lacked malice when attacking, causing it to be difficult to sense their intent prior to the attack, as a side effect of the indoctrination required to make them act on order 66.  The Jedi thus couldn't sense a warning prior to a surprise attack as they usually would.  However, I can't recall where I had read this.

Comment: Vader also has the jedi ability to absorb energy.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51536/discussion-on-answer-by-dvk-in-florida-why-cant-the-rebels-kill-vader-like-the).

Comment: "The Dark Side is stronger." Yoda disagrees.

Comment: The Dark Side is stronger in combat. Otherwise Yoda would not be in hiding. The Light Side is "stronger" overall because good guys are fated to win in the end and bad guys are fated to lose. Dark Side = quick and easy power with immediate victory, Light Side = victorious destiny eventually.

Comment: @DVK-in-Florida You [have a typo in #4](https://themeatshield.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/midichlorians.jpg)

Comment: 5. Pretty sure Yoda explicitely states that the dark side is not stronger, only easier.

Answer (score 6):

In ESB, Han Solo (who shoots first, BTW) shoots Vader 5 times and he just fends the blasts off with the palms of his hands. His suit must therefore be armored against blasters.

Comment: Wellll, unless he’s using the Force. Regardless, can you provide some evidence that he’s not using the Force here?

Comment: According to the Legends book "I, Jedi", Vader used the Force to defend himself against these bolts, not his armor. Luke Skywalker thinks he used Force Absorb, but it's also possible he used Force Deflection. Source: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Force_deflection#Notable_uses

Comment: His suit is armored, but he was absorbing the blaster's through the force. You get an upvote for standing up to the non-canon canon.

Comment: I'm so fed up with this "Han shot first" crap. Anyone who's seen the original cut knows the truth -- *Greebo never got a shot off*. Han was the *only* one to shoot... ;-)

Comment: [Crushgaunt](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjP3K7ai7jRAhVj0YMKHbSrCc4QFggcMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstarwars.wikia.com%2Fwiki%2FCrushgaunt&usg=AFQjCNGZfNJYTKkmaAnK1zJychYVm8MTrg&sig2=1UXOtbXO3rM1gAZWSx1hfA)

Comment: I was going to post this answer. Here is the video clip: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHH6YVHGh90

Comment: @DevSolar - Greedo shot first.

Comment: @Adamant Maybe it depends on your point of view. ;)